# This rhyme could save your life!

Tags: rhyme

This rhyme could save you!

> Red touches yellow,
>   
>  kills a fellow
> Red touches black, 
> there's a venom  lack
>   
> Black tail and mouth of cotton,
>   
> Will kill if trodden
>   
> Brown tail and aquatic
>   
> Life fanatic

What is being described?

**Hint #1**

> They are animals

**Hint #2**

> 4 are being described

Comment: why the downvotes? if you are going to downvote tell me why so I can fix the problem

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can surmise the reason. While a puzzle is meant to obscure information, this is a very common mnemonic (at least the first 4 lines) that is meant to convey information. It's equivalent to posting a question asking what ROY G BIV means. So it's not like there's something that you need to fix here, it just doesn't seem to fit within the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rhyme is describing

> Snakes

Red touches yellow, 
kills a fellow

> Coral Snake (venomous)

Red touches black, 
there's a venom lack

> California Mountain King Snake

Black tail and mouth of cotton, 
Will kill if trodden

> Cottonmouth Snake

Brown tail and aquatic 
Life fanatic

> Brown Water Snake

Comment: You got it! Well done